# Power BI how to pull in tags of work items

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata, analytics

I am trying to pull in the tags that are associated with a work item view the Analytics View of Power BI OR using the ODATA feed from AzureDevops. Is this currently possible? The work items table natively lacks this column.

There is mention in the documentation that there is a column of csv values containing the names of the tags but I am missing it? I was hoping to filter work items in a Power BI report by tag.

Thanks!